# How to specify Gradle wrapper with Jenkins JobDSL?

Tags: jenkins-job-dsl

The JobDSL spec currently has:

```
job {
  steps {
    gradle('build')
  }
}
```

but that creates a job that errors with:

```
FATAL: Unable to find Gradle Wrapper
```

How does one specify the Gradle wrapper to use? I don't see it documented in https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Job-reference#gradle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a standard thing to do, you have to escape out to a configure block:

```
  job {
    steps {
      gradle('clean build', '--info --refresh-dependencies', true) {
          it / wrapperScript('$NEBULA_HOME/gradlew')
      }
    }
  }
```